# Hide and unhide specific rows depending on a number selected.

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I am creating a user form on Excel where I would like to hide and unhide entire rows depending on a data validation list which goes from 1 to 4. (data validation in cell M5)

Here what I want to do: 
If number 1 is selected in M5, I want to hide rows 9:11 and 17:20
If number 2 is selected in M5, I want to hide rows 10:11 and 18:20
If number 3 is selected in M5, I want to hide rows 11 and 20

All the rows I would like to hide contain a date picker option in column E. (I am happy to drop the date picker option if it is a must)

I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you all. 
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a worksheet change event by putting something like this in the worksheet object in the VBE

```
Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
If Not Intersect(target, Range("M5")) Is Nothing Then
    ActiveSheet.Rows("9:20").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    If target = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows("9:11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows("17:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf target = 2 Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows("10:11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows("18:20").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf target = 3 Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(11).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows(20).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf target = 4 Then
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

It checks that the change was in your validation, then checks the value, hiding what it should hide. I have it unhide everything at first so you don't have to worry about something remaining hidden after changing the value.

Be sure it's in the sheet module of the sheet you want this to happen on -

[image]

Comment: Thank you Raystafarian, I get an error on the word "target", second line. Variable not defined. I am not sure what went wrong

Comment: Did you put it in the sheet module? The target will be whatever is changed.

Comment: The sheet name is called "request to travel" I changed it but I still don't know why it is not picking it up. My VBA knowledge is very limited..

Comment: Don't change the macro's name - it should be `sub worksheet_change(byval target as range)` just put it in the "request to travel" sheet's module.

Comment: It has worked. I am really glad. thank you so much for your help :) really appreciated.

Comment: Great, be sure to click the green checkmark next to the answer to mark your question as solved.